# How to compile and run on a real iPad if the source code is from a book author?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I got a book for iPad programming and there is source code in a CD-ROM.  When I compile it and run on a simulator, everything works.  But if I target to a new iPad to see the app's performance, it gives:

> Check dependencies
>        Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: Chen Li' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in
>   the default keychain

Is there a way to solve this?  Or else it seems like another method is to create a new project and add those source code file one by one, but there probably is a better way?

(because I joined the Apple developer's program, I can run programs on a real iPad if it is my own code... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 4, go select your *project* on the left pane listing all files.
Then select your *target* and go to *Build Settings*.
When you are there, search for *Code Signing*.

Make sure you select your profile there, and not the book's author's one, since you do not have his profile installed on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an apple iOS developer program membership in order to test on real devices. Also if you have it, this requires a couple of setup steps.

Since you have the developer program configured, you need to update the project settings to use your profile.

Go to the project settings -> build settings -> code signing And update the appropriate settings. In Xcode 4.3 there is an automatic selection option.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the source code from CD has already set a `Code Signing Identify`, but can't find in your profiles lib, you have to change the `Code Signing Identify` to your profile.

Go to project target `Build Settings` and change the `Code Signing Identify`.